# Convert Virtual Machine disks to bootable images

Tags: windows

I have a couple of virtual machines that, over a few months, I have installed numerous pieces of software upon. Unfortunately, for some of the software to run at a usable speed, I need to run it on a real computer, where it can access more memory, computing power, and bandwidth. So, does anyone know of some software that can "burn" a virtual machine disk onto a flash drive or HDD so it can be booted from? I would prefer if said software runs on windows (otherwise I would need to make a bootable linux drive to make another bootable drive). I would also prefer something that I can point at a vmdk and a drive and walk away (as opposed to a utility that can do this, but requires me to "walk it though" through several steps of extraction and conversion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For windows 
Most cloning packages will do it.

1. You have **imagex.exe** by Microsoft

   sysprep /generalize

   Boot from Windows PE/Windows 7 DVD

   net use (drive letter):  (unc)

   and save image to network share.

On the real hardware boot the same way except use imagex with the command line arguments to restore the image.

1. I believe Acronis True Image can do this also.

   Install Acrnois inside the VM and attach a USB hard drive.

   Run  sysprep /generalize  **This will help with driver issues**

   Save image to ext usb hard drive.

   Make bootable acronis restore CD.

   Attach ext USB hard drive to real hardware.

   Boot real PC with Acronis CD/DVD

   Restore from ext USB hard drive.

   Reboot

   Wait for sysprep to complete

   install drivers for real hardware.